# Orientability of Möbius band

Tags: differential-geometry

Can we cover the Möbius band with a finite atlas such that the determinant of the Jacobian of **each** transition map is negative everyhwere?

Comment: It seems doable with 3 charts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Olivier's comment, you can cover the Möbius band with three rectangles which overlap in thin strips. You can arrange that the transition maps are basically reflection through the $x$-axis, which is a map with negative determinant. One way to visualize this construction is as a band with three half-twists, which is indeed diffeomorphic to the usual Möbius band.